# Not able to click on uib-tabs element link using protractor

Tags: html, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude="">
    <li ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]" 
     class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope 
     active"index="0" select="vm.setTab('overview')">
        <a href="" ng-click="select($event)" class="nav-link ng-binding" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">
            <uib-tab-heading class="text-center ng-scope">
                <span class="text-overflow">Overview</span>
            </uib-tab-heading>
        </a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]" 
    class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" index="1" 
    select="vm.setTab('jobListing')">
       <a href="" ng-click="select($event)" class="nav-link ng-binding" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">
           <uib-tab-heading class="text-center ng-scope">
               <span class="text-overflow">Job Listing</span>
           </uib-tab-heading>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Above is auto generated html code. I want to click on 'Job Listing' using protractor for that I have tried below thing but doesn't work.Please help.
       `$('li[select="vm.setTab(\'jobListing\']"').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.nav .nav-item', 'Job Listing')).click();
```